# How can I identify scatter plot data points that are included in a D3 brush?

Tags: zooming, d3.js

I'm fairly new to d3 but have been able to use a lot of the examples out there create an SVG scatter plot to which I added a brush to allow the user to higlight a subset of that data.

```
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

 svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "brush")
.call(d3.svg.brush().x(x).y(y)
.on("brushstart", brushstart)
.on("brush", brushmove)
.on("brushend", brushend));


 function brushstart() {
 svg.classed("selecting", true);
 }

 function brushmove() {
var e = d3.event.target.extent();
circle.classed("selected", function(d) {
return e[0][0] <= d[0] && d[0] <= e[1][0]
    && e[0][1] <= d[1] && d[1] <= e[1][1];
 });
}

function brushend() {
   svg.classed("selecting", !d3.event.target.empty());
}
```

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is take that highlighted region and explode it (zoom) into another SVG on the screen to let the user drill in for more detail. So what I'm trying to do is figure out the best way to identify those data which exist within the brush.extent that should be displayed in the other chart.

I thought about trying to loop through each data point, comparing it's coordinates to the boundaries of the extent but that seems like it will be slow if I begin to deal with large scatter plots.   Are there better ways I can get the subset of data more efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Crossfilter library](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) to handle the filtering for me here.  They've done the hard work to make sure things are efficient, and the API is pretty straightforward.

I've built up [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzBeA/1/) with the basics, but basically it amounts to these lines of code:

```
var xf = crossfilter(data);
var xDim = xf.dimension(function(d) { return d[0]; });
var yDim = xf.dimension(function(d) { return d[1]; });

brush.on('brush', function() {
    var extent = brush.extent();
    xDim.filterRange([extent[0][0], extent[1][0]]);
    yDim.filterRange([extent[0][1], extent[1][1]]);
    update();
});
```

Comment: Using your fiddle I cannot figure out how to use the "brush". I think I can create a "brush" by Command+clicking (Mac) on the graph, and then dragging across the graph. That creates a window which contains the "brush" and shows the contained circles. I expected a "result" also, though, and got none. Is that because the code is not extended to do something with the circles in the "brush", or am I missing some mouse or keystroke functions? I sort of expect the "brush" to behave **cumulatively** like a drawing app's eraser/brush, for example. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *cumulatively* here. D3's brush is not like the brush of a drawing app: you aren't adding to the screen but rather selecting.  The example given addresses the OP's goal of filtering the data based on the `brush.extent`, but it doesn't do anything meaningful (other than show and hide the corresponding points).